# Counting empty values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, acrobat

I am using JavaScript in Acrobat 9 to create a test for my American history students. I want to not count the answers they did not answer against them. Here is what I have so far:

```
var arrTest = "cell.1", "cell.2", "cell.3" , "cell.4"); //Will have more than four
count = 0, i = arrTest.length;  while (i--) {
    if (typeof arrTest[i] === "undefined")
    count++;
}
```

BTW, is there any good learning material?

Comment: Sorry to pick at small things but you should really mention the language you're using in your tags. You'll get a lot more answers most of the time.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Acrobat allows one to access the answers, but your JavaScript is slightly wrong:

```
var arrTest = [ "cell.1", "cell.2", "cell.3" , "cell.4"],
    count = 0,
    i = arrTest.length;

while (i--) {
    //Assume PDFdoc is a var referencing your Acrobat document - not sure how it works there.
    if (typeof PDFdoc.getField(arrTest[i]).value === "undefined") {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran through Firebug and keep getting tripped up on the IF statement.

Comment: Well PDFdoc.getField( xxxx ).value is an Acrobat thing, it wouldn't run in Firebug. I should have